# Python: Compare two lists with pairs and create a new list based upon membership and values

Tags: python, list

So, I have a list:

```
list = [['Tuesday', 5], ['Friday', 2], ['Sunday', 3], ['Thursday', 1]]
```

I'm looking to build code that figures out that Mon, Wed, and Sat are missing from the list and adds them in with 0 values. The resulting list should be sorted as shown. So, the new list would look like:

[**['Monday', 0]**, ['Tuesday', 5], **['Wednesday', 0]**, ['Thursday', 1], ['Friday', 2], **['Saturday', 0]**, ['Sunday', 3]]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why the values next to weekday change?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit of what you're trying to accomplish? Perhaps a dictionary would be better than a list in this situation?

Comment: True, maybe a dictionary is better. I'm looking to have a piece of code that can read a given list of days and corresponding integers, such as that one shown. So, it would look at those pairs and realize that there are missing days. Then, it would insert the missing days and just apply values of zero. I was thinking to do a comparison with a list like: weekdays = [['Monday', 0], ['Tuesday', 0], ['Wednesday', 0], ['Thursday', 0], ['Friday', 0], ['Saturday', 0], ['Sunday', 0]]

Comment: @falsetru they shouldn't change, that was a typo, I just fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dictionary, especially [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
>>> lst = [['Tuesday', 5], ['Friday', 2], ['Sunday', 3], ['Thursday', 1]]
>>> weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
                'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
>>> d = dict(lst)
>>> [[wd, d.get(wd, 0)] for wd in weekdays]  # d.get(wd, 0) returns 0 for missing day
[['Monday', 0], ['Tuesday', 5], ['Wednesday', 0], ['Thursday', 1],
 ['Friday', 2], ['Saturday', 0], ['Sunday', 3]]
```

BTW, it's not a good idea to use `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin type/funciton [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Comment: this works great, thanks! i see that you used a list comprehension to look in weekdays and pull the value for the same key in 1st, which was converted to a dict. what i don't understand is why d.get(wd,0) does not replace all values with 0 across the board. how does it know to replace only the missing values with zero?

Comment: @alldayiwonder, `dict.get(..)` works like `dict[..]`; except .. instead of raising `KeyError` for non-existing key, it returns the default value (`0` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Check out dict.update.  If you start with a dictionary that maps all the weekdays to zero, then update with the values you read in, I think it should produce the result you want:

```
fullweek = {'Monday':0, 'Tuesday': 0, 'Wednesday': 0, 'Thursday': 0, 'Friday': 0, 'Saturday': 0, 'Sunday': 0}
newdays = {'Tuesday':5, 'Friday':2, 'Sunday':3, 'Thursday':1}
fullweek.update(newdays)
```

Sorting would then happen when you want to format the result, for example,

```
for day in ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Friday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Sunday', 'Saturday']:
    print day+' : %d'%fullweek[day]
```

Comment: You still need to sort the data.

Comment: @Matthias : Or maintain a list / tuple of the keys. I suppose a sophisticated program would pull them from datetime, which is locale-sensitive.

Comment: @Matthias: Thanks, lazy answer.  Will edit to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template with default values and use list comprehension to build your result array of arrays

```
#template with default values. Change the value from 0 to whatever if needed
template=[['Monday', 0], ['Tuesday', 0], ['Wednesday', 0], ['Thursday', 0], ['Friday', 0], ['Saturday', 0], ['Sunday', 0]]
#current data
data=[['Tuesday', 5], ['Friday', 2], ['Sunday', 3], ['Thursday', 1]]

#build a dictionary to make lookups easy
dictData=dict(data)

#use list comprehension to insert entries from data. If not in data use from template
result = [[x[0], dictData[x[0]]] if x[0] in dictData  else x for x in template]
print result
```

Output:

```
[['Monday', 0], ['Tuesday', 5], ['Wednesday', 0], ['Thursday', 1], ['Friday', 2], ['Saturday', 0], ['Sunday', 3]]
```